# Is it possible to get on one of the skyscrapers in Warsaw?

Tags: warsaw

It would be really great to see the city from up above. But it seems that most of the tall buildings are business centers with restricted access. Are there any publicly accessible rooftops or observation points in Warsaw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about the skyscrapers, but it is definitely possible to access [the viewing area on the 30th floor of the Palace of Culture and Science](http://www.pkin.pl/en/taras-widokowy/), which is right in the centre of the city.

Comment: I've heard it said that the view from the top of the Palace of Culture and Science is the best in Warsaw, because you can't see the Palace of Culture and Science from there.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert **LOL**